IPTABLES - Can't redirect HTTPS traffic to external proxy
I have a external proxy server connected by VPN (IPSEC) to my main branch, and i'm trying to redirect all users HTTP / HTTPS traffic to this proxy.
Scenario
Users -> Gateway (Main Branch) -> IPSEC -> Proxy (transparent mode)
In my Gateway (Main Branch) I have this test iptables rule, that is forwarding all the TPC / UDP traffic to the Proxy server.
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.60.90 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.31.0.1
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.60.90 -p udp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.31.0.1

In Proxy server I have the followed rules
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.60.90/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment ArticaSquidTransparent -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8081
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.60.90/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment ArticaSquidTransparent -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080

Everything is working correctly, HTTP traffic is send to proxy, DNS are also working, the only exeption is the HTTPS traffic, I can see the HTTPS traffic inside the proxy access.log but on client side I got a timeout
1722265740.867      1 192.168.60.90 TCP_TUNNEL/200 0 CONNECT cnn.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/51.210.183.2:443 - mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" webfilterpolicy:%200%0D%0A exterr="-|-"

Anyone can help me to understant if I'm missing so iptable rule to handle the HTTPS traffic?
